# Error class not found when readObject from InputStream

Tags: java, jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception

I try to write JRVirtualPrintPage object into OutputStream in order to wite it to persistence file.

But when i read  from InputStream, i couldn't load a class which i defined when perform percentile calculation

My code at below:

```
private void writePages() throws IOException, JRException {

 OutputStream pos = new OutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(pos);

    List pages = print.getPages();

    numPages = pages == null ? 0 : pages.size();
    writeInt(numPages);

    pageFilePointers = new long[pages.size()];
    long pfpOffset = writeObject(pageFilePointers);


    for(int i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
        if (interrupted)
            return;

        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            throw new JRException("Current thread interrupted.");
        }

        JRVirtualPrintPage vpage = (JRVirtualPrintPage)pages.get(i);

        oos.writeObject(vpage);


        for (JRPrintElement jrPrintElement : elements) {
            oos.writeObject(jrPrintElement);
        }

        pageFilePointers[i] = writeBytes(pos.getBytes());
    }

    long saveFP = file.getFilePointer();
    file.seek(pfpOffset);
    writeObject(pageFilePointers);
    file.seek(saveFP);
}

private void readPages() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    int numPages = readInt();
    pageFilePointers = (long[])readObject();

    AJPersistenceInputStream pis = new AJPersistenceInputStream();
    file.seek(pageFilePointers[0]);
    byte[] pageBytes = readBytes();
    pis.reset(pageBytes);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(pis);

    JRVirtualPrintPage page = (JRVirtualPrintPage)ois.readObject();

    if (startIndex == endIndex) {
        for(int i=1; i<=startIndex; i++)
            page = getPrintPage(pis, ois, i);
        print.addPage(page);
    } else {
        endIndex = Math.min(endIndex, pageFilePointers.length-1);

        for(int i=0; i<=endIndex; i++) {
            if (i>0)    // else already read page index == 0
                page = getPrintPage(pis, ois, i);
            if (i >= startIndex)
                print.addPage(page);
        }
    }
}
```

I got an error at below:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alu.vital.vq.jasper.aggregation.AJPercentileAggregator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1610)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:499)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplatePrintText.readObject(JRTemplatePrintText.java:91)
```

The "com.alu.vital.vq.jasper.aggregation.AJPercentileAggregator" class is class which i defined to perform percentile calculation. It was compiled when build report.

Why do i use JRVirtualPrintPage object to write into OutputStream and when read from InputStream, i also cast object to JRVirtualPrintPage type, why does this exception occur?

Please help me explain more details this. And how can i fix it? I think it relave to new Virtualize mechanism because this issue only occurs when i upgrade *JasperReports* from 3.7.4 to 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in lines

> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1989)
>
> at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:499)

from bottom of stack trace.

It seems that your JRVirtualPrintPage class has a field of type AJPercentileAggregator.  Therefore when you are serializing JRVirtualPrintPage, is serializing all its fields, so AJPercentileAggregator as well.

You can :

1. Write custom serializer to JRVirtualPrintPage which skips field of type AJPercentileAggregator.
2. Mark this field as transient, which skips it from serializing

Comment: Thanks for your response, Grzesuav.
But, AJPercentileAggregator itself contains value that i performed percentile calculation, it shouldn't skip from serializing because i will miss its value when export report.

Comment: Ok, so class AJPercentileAggregator should be visible during deserialization, but it isn't. Do you  serializing using older version of JasperReports and deserializing using new version ?

Comment: No, i don't, Grzesuav. 
I serializing and deserializing using JasperReports (v. 3.7.4), my report can view, it can load AJPercentileAggregator object when read Object from ObjectOutputStream.
And when i try to upgrade to Jasper 5.0.1, It couldn't load AJPercentileAggregator object.

Comment: Ok, for clarification, AJPercentileAggregator is class from JasperReports library or you own class ?

Comment: It's my own class. I defined it to perform percentile calculation. It extends Number class and implements Serializable interface.

Comment: It seems that jasperReport don't see it on its classpath, JasperReport is run in thesame VM or in another process? It need setting separate classpath ? Does your class in on classpath ?

Comment: Hi Crzesuav, they run in the same VM. I set it in classpath.

Comment: Hmm I have no more suggestions. From given stack trace is seems that class **com.alu.vital.vq.jasper.aggregation.AJPercentileAggregator** is not visible by class loading used by deserialization.